# Need to increase throughput rate for Azure Function App

Tags: .net, azure-functions, azure-eventhub, throughput

I have current throughput rates of ~11 records/sec(1 event has 1 record) for my event-triggered Azure function app. It takes data from Eventhub and posts it to an API endpoint. I have been tweaking the host.json settings(maxBatchSize, prefetchCount) but they haven't increased the rates.

- App runs on .NET so cant even try to increase workers manually using FUNCTIONS_WORKER_PROCESS_COUNT.
- API endpoint has a throttle of 100 records/sec.

Below lie some test results:

| Test | Domain | App Service Plan | Instance | maxBatchSize | prefetchCount | Avg CPU Usage | Data Transferred(records) | Total Time taken | Throughput Rate(Records/sec) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Products | S1 | 1 | 100 | 200 | 100 | 3281 | 0:18:31 | 2.95 |
| 2 | Products | P2V2 | 1 | 100 | 200 | 11.5 | 34264 | 0:48:57 | 11.67 |
| 3 | SalesOrder | P1V2 | 2 | 64 | 128 | 11 (for both instances) | 33816 | 0:49:25 | 11.41 |

Appreciate your help here.

Comment: have to tried on (Premium) Consumption tier?

Comment: No, because CPU usage is just 11 for premium instances here. Didn't feel the need to. Can you please explain how (Premium) Consumption tier will help?

Comment: there are only so many parallel Functions that can run on one ASP instance. In consumption plan it can scale out over many instances at any time. I was just wondering why you didnt include Consumption tier in your tests

Comment: Right. I got your point about parellel instances. However, I did manually scale out to 3 instances. Throughput rate still remained the same. That is why I didn't move it from App service to consumption plan.

Comment: Is there not any other way than parallel instances to increase the throughout rate here? By tweaking host.json settings? I was under the impression, I could increase it that way

Comment: Usually people start in consumption tier and only go to ASP if they have a reason to

Comment: Okay. I'll try this in consumption plan. However that's just for parallel instances right? What about host.json settings. Can they only limit the rate and not increase it?

Comment: Does the below answer help?

Answer (score 0):

*One way to increase concurrency for single instance is to change [maxConcurrentRequests](http://maxConcurrentRequests).*  **For example,** if you had a function app with two HTTP functions and maxConcurrentRequests requests set to 25, a request to either HTTP trigger would count towards the shared 25 concurrent requests. When that function app is scaled to 10 instances, the ten functions effectively allow 250 concurrent requests (10 instances * 25 concurrent requests per instance).

*Second way is to scale function app instances itself.* Below is a [table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale#scale) of scaling plan provided by Function App:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for getting back. Below are my open points:
    1) I dont think maxConcurrentRequests works for event-triggered functions. If it does, is a request equivalent to an event? Please let me know.
    2) I got the part about changing the plan, however, I still don't get why I haven't been able to increase throughput rate by increasing the CPU and number of instances manually. If you may, Please help me out with this. I can share further test results.
    3) I don't get the difference between the definition of consumption plan and premium plan in the pic. Please elaborate.

Comment: 1 - Yes, request is equivalent to event and maxConcurrentRequests work for all triggers., 2- By increasing CPU - where? Function app is PaaS offering. Number of instances increment will increase throughput to an extent (depends on the load), 3 - I have also shared link of the table in my answer, pls visit there to know more details.